# Shipping discount based on chosen payment method in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, discount, shipping-method, payment-method

I'm currently trying to apply a discount on shipping if a customer chooses a certain payment method.

For some reason, this applies the discount regardless of which payment method is chosen.

The code I'm using in `functions.php` is:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    
    $min = 25;
    $min2 = 25;
    $max = 50;
    $discount_percent = 50;
    $payment_method = 'clearpay';
    $chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');

    // Get cart total
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;

    // Condition
    if ( $cart_total >= $min && $cart_total <= $max && $payment_method == $chosen_payment_method ) {
        // (Multiple)
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            // Get rate cost            
            $cost = $rates[$rate_key]->cost;
            
            // Set rate cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $cost - ( ( $cost * $discount_percent ) / 100 );
        }
        
        wc_add_notice( 
            sprintf( 'Congratulations! Your shipping is now 50&#37; off!' , 
                wc_price( WC()->cart->total ), 
                wc_price( $minimum )
            ), 'success' 
        );
        
    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
do_action( 'woocommerce_set_cart_cookies',  true );
```

---

Any idea what’s wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains unnecessary variables that you are either not using or using incorrectly. It is certainly not mentioned in your question description.

So to apply a shipping discount based on the chosen payment method you can use.

```php
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) { 
    // Payment methods - Add several if desired, separated by a comma
    $payment_methods = array( 'bacs', 'clearpay' );
    
    // Get chosen payment method
    $chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');
    
    // Compare, found = continue
    if ( in_array( $chosen_payment_method, $payment_methods ) ) {
        // Discount percent
        $discount_percent = 50;
        
        // Loop trough
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            // Get rate cost            
            $cost = $rates[$rate_key]->cost;
            
            // Set rate cost
            $rates[$rate_key]->cost = $cost - ( ( $cost * $discount_percent ) / 100 );
        }   
    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
```

Note: Don't forget to empty the cart, to refresh the WooCommerce shipping caches

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm doing in order to get flat discount amounts for different payment methods

You can adapt it to your case

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','mlnc_add_discount', 20, 1 );

function mlnc_add_discount( $cart_object ) {

$label= __('');
$discount = 0;

$chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method'); //get the selected payment method

switch($chosen_payment_method){
case 'paypal':    
$label = __( "PayPal Discount" );
// The discount amount to apply
$discount = 5;
break;
case 'bacs':    
$label = __( "Direct Bank Transfer Discount" );
// The discount amount to apply
$discount = 10;
break; 
case 'cod':    
$label = __( "Cash on Delivery Discount" );
// The discount amount to apply
$discount = 0;
break; 
}

// Add the discount
$cart_object->add_fee( $label, - $discount, false );
}
```